# Can third parties be given access to a DynamoDB table to download data?

Tags: web-scraping, amazon-dynamodb

I have a [web-scraping](/questions/tagged/web-scraping) algorithm that feeds data into a [dynamodb](/questions/tagged/dynamodb) table everyday. I want this data to be made public in a way that anyone (people without an AWS account, too) can download this data as a [csv](/questions/tagged/csv). Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Not currently. Access control for a DynamoDB table is restricted to IAM principles within the table's account. One option would be to periodically [export the DynamoDB table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/S3DataExport.HowItWorks.html) data to S3 in csv and share the csv file from the S3 bucket.